# Pick Latest Entry of a specific ID from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

| Report Number | Department | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77e1117e-a248-4781-866f-704bea114d11 | Dep. 01 | 2022-06-13 10:12:42.000 | 685.10 |
| 77e1117e-a248-4781-866f-704bea114d11 | Dep. 01 | 2022-06-13 10:12:42.000 | 0.19 |
| a34f8425-c64f-47a9-b947-49e7d2fd5bba | Dep. 01 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 102.45 |
| a34f8425-c64f-47a9-b947-49e7d2fd5bba | Dep. 01 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 427.13 |
| h94e8421-h79j-25q9-n478-58w7f2af6ffe | Dep.02 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 98.98 |
| h94e8421-h79j-25q9-n478-58w7f2af6ffe | Dep. 02 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 500.50 |

These are two reports, each with two entries, generated at a different time and yielding a different price.

I would like to have a script/code that can automatically choose the latest date and return the sum of prices corresponding to that report number per department.

The output should be something like that:

| Report Number | Department | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a34f8425-c64f-47a9-b947-49e7d2fd5bba | Dep. 01 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 529.58 |
| h94e8421-h79j-25q9-n478-58w7f2af6ffe | Dep. 02 | 2022-06-13 13:16:45.000 | 599.48 |

Comment: So is your data stored as `xml`? Why not store the data in a normalised format?

Comment: *"Pick latest entry"* is misleading here - your sample output show an aggregate of the price grouped by ReviewNr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ReviewNr, [Date], Sum(Price)
from myTable
where ReviewNr in (select top(1) reviewNr from myTable order by [Date] desc)
group by ReviewNr, [Date];
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b633c1334933bf6e5acfb20d44422045)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY Date DESC ) AS RowNumber,
        SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ) PriceSum
    FROM WhateverTableItIs
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

(Why have you posted HTML when your question is about SQL?!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can aggregate the rows for each `ReportNumber` then use `ROW_NUMBER` by date

```sql
SELECT
  Department,
  ReportNumber,
  Date,
  Price
FROM (
    SELECT
      Department,
      ReportNumber,
      Date,
      SUM(Price) Price,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      Department,
      Date,
      ReportNumber
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9800eb72bd0b8018f9fc312e43841243)